# OPENQUERY option to bulk insert data into a table on remote server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have SQL Server 2014 and was trying to find out if there's a way to bulk insert data into a table on a remote server like below.

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY([REMOTESERVER], 
'BULK INSERT [DBNAME].[dbo].[demo] FROM ''\\Share\data\demo.dat'' 
WITH (DATAFILETYPE = ''widenative'')');
```

Comment: So, what's the question here?

Comment: `BULK INSERT` has no result set, so invoking it with `OPENQUERY` makes no sense. You can use `EXEC ... AT [REMOTESERVER]` to execute arbitrary statements remotely.